# What was the inspector's theory, if any?

Tags: hanns-heinz-ewers

In the short story "The Spider" by Hanns Heinz Ewers, a medical student plans expose the reason behind some apparent suspicious suicides, unsurprisingly later revealed to be murders, and supernatural. The medical student claims, through vague intimations, to have a plan to get to the bottom of the mysterious suicides, though he does not:

> I told him that six o'clock of a Friday is an occult hour. It is the
>   last hour of the Jewish week; the hour when Christ disappeared from
>   his tomb and descended into hell. That he would do well to remember
>   that the three suicides had taken place at approximately that hour.
>   That was all I could tell him just then, I said, but I pointed him to
>   The Revelations of St. John.
>
> The Inspector assumed the look of a man who understood all that I had
>   been saying, then he asked me to come back that evening.
>
> I returned, precisely on time, and noted a copy of the New Testament
>   on the Inspector's desk. I had, in the meantime, been at the
>   Revelations myself without however having understood a syllable.
>   Perhaps the Inspector was cleverer than I. Very politely-nay-
>   deferentially, he let me know that, despite my extremely vague
>   intimations, he believed he grasped my line of thought and was ready
>   to expedite my plan in every way.

Initally it *seems* as if the Inspector had no idea, but that he merely wanted to appear as if he were intelligent and understood what the student was saying.

However, later we see that at least part of this theory is correct. The suicides must happen at 6:00 in the afternoon on a Friday:

> At five o'clock, I was at the end of my strength. I'm perfectly aware
>   now that there is a relationship between my despair and the "sixth
>   hour" that was so significant in the previous weeks. I no longer laugh
>   at the trick I played the Inspector.

As such, it seems like there might be something to the Biblical connection, and the Inspector might actually have understood something about the nature of the murders, while it's the medical student who's foolish. What, if anything, was the Inspector's theory about the connection to Revelation?